# Display Table in Twig from a variable in controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am new to symfony.SO please find me a solution.On my controller

```
$table="<table><tr><th>Test</th></tr><tr><td>Show Test</td></tr></table>"
```

And I have Passed it to the  twig from the controller like

```
return $this->render('lottery/transactions/trnissuenote/show.html.twig', array(
            'table'=>$table
        ));
```

And on my twig

```
<div >
                                 {{table}}       
</div>
```

But i didnt get the table structure .Just echoing it.How will i get the table structure.Help me find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to display it using `raw` filter. Since by default `{{}}` escapes html content of a variable.

```
<div>
    {{ table|raw }}
</div>
```

Read more: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html